# Multithreading Prevents UI From Freezing, but Is Somehow Slower Than Singlethreading?

Tags: c#

I attempted to implement threading into my software to prevent the UI from freezing while a nested foreach loop is going on in the background. The problem I've run into is while this worked, it slowed down the processing speed by a TON. What used to take 10 seconds now takes 1 minute. How I went about putting threading in goes like this:

The user presses the button(this is the code for the button)

```
CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
new Thread(() => beginSearchAll()) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
```

The button calls the beginSearchAll method

```
public void beginSearchAll()
    {
        if (FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(fsd.getSkypePath()).ProductVersion != "6.16")
        {
            logcount = 0;
            counter = 0;
            listViewEx1.Items.Clear();
            println("\nSearching all contacts...");
            ListView.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            fsd.searchAllNormal(s, this);
        }
        else
        {
            logcount = 0;
            counter = 0;
            listViewEx1.Items.Clear();
            println("\nSearching all contacts...");         
            fsd.searchAllDeob(s, this);
        }
        println("\nComplete!")
    }
```

The search all method will check what version of Skype the user is on, and then run the searchAllNormal method(the one where all the work is done) which is located in a seperate class called 'fsd'. I won't include the whole method, but the gist of it.

```
public static void searchAllNormal(Skype s, Form1 f1)
    {
        foreach (User user in s.Friends)
        {
            foreach (string log in Directory.GetFiles(f1.path, "debug*.log"))
            {
                string[] fileToRead = File.ReadAllLines(log);
                foreach (string line in fileToRead)
                {
                    //parse data
                    f1.addToList(user,c,data);
                }
             }
        }
    }
```

After finding the data for a user, it will call a method to add the data to the listView located in Form1

```
public void addToList(User user, string c, string b)
    {
        listViewEx1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(b)
        {
            SubItems = { user.Handle, user.FullName, c }                    
        });
    }
```

Then it obviously repeats for every single user on my Skype contacts. When I change

```
 new Thread(() => beginSearchAll()) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
```

to

```
beginSearchAll();
```

It freezes the UI, but goes faster. Is it possible to retain the speed, but also have the UI not freeze?

Comment: Set the thread with higher priority?

Comment: Dont use "CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;", use a proper Invoke.

Comment: Not sure what Skype is but probably better off passing a list of friends instead.  Also passing the form will definitely not help.  Try passing a list instead.  Checkout BackgroundWorker Class, and OnRunWorkerCompleted.  When OnRunWorkerCompleted is raised, populate the listViewEx1 with the result

Comment: X, that works but it freezes the UI

Comment: You must rewrite your code. Use "Invoke" only to update the UI. The "hard" job must be in a new thread.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - Should I be using your code when I call the f1.addToList method instead?

Comment: Yes, Invoke only "f1.addToList(user,c,data);"

Comment: Is this how it should be?  new Thread(() => f1.addToList(user, c, date)) { IsBackground = true }.Start();

Comment: You probably should consider having the thread create a list of objects that it returns to the UI thread, and have the UI thread update the `ListView` from that list by calling `ListView.BeginUpdate`, then populating all of the items, and finally calling `ListView.EndUpdate`. Also, rather than calling `ReadAllLines`, which loads the entire file, call `File.ReadLines`, which reads the file a line at a time.

Comment: Jim, how would I create the list? Should I do a tuple list?

Comment: Assuming this is Windows Forms, the first thing I'd try is a `List<ListViewItem>`. That should work. If that doesn't work, then I'd probably define a class that contains the data you want to display in the list view, and create a list of those. In my opinion, a list of `Tuple` is a last resort if nothing else works.